# replacing several string occurrences in r

Tags: r, gsub

I want to replace several strings with one. I've researched and found that gsub can replace elements but one at a time.

If I do this I get a warning saying that only the first one was used.

```
data$EVTYPE <- gsub( c("x","y") , "xy", data$EVTYPE)
```

I am trying now with sapply

`data$EVTYPE <- sapply(data$EVTYPE, gsub, c("x", "y"), "xy")` but it's been already more than 5 minutes and is still processing. I will get a stack overflow message any time now. :-/ Is there an elegant short solution for this? Is there a package I can use for this? It needs to be small because I need to do this for several cases where I have duplicate names.

Comment: Are you looking for `gsub( "x|y" , "xy", data$EVTYPE)`?  Please provide a reproducible example with desired output.

Comment: As @Frank mentioned a reproducible example is needed to know whether you need word boundaries (`\\b`)  or not.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are passing a vector of patterns and gsub does not know how to handle that. What string are you trying to replace with what other string?

Comment: I am doing this data$EVTYPE <- sapply(data$EVTYPE, gsub, c("COLD TEMPERATURE", "COLD TEMPERATURES"), "COLD" ), I know already that gsub doesn't accept more than one argument as pattern, but this doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Thank you @Frank. I didn't know that I could separate them with a pipe. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your useful comments. It was done as Frank suggested. `gsub( "x|y" , "xy", data$EVTYPE).`

Instead of using a vector.

Answer (score 0):

For the cold temperature case, you could use `gsub("COLD TEMPERATURES?", "COLD", data$EVTYPE)` it's worth spending a little time getting one's head around the basics of regular expressions. There are lots of tutorials including [this one](http://regexone.com).